# SQL Server Update - Validar filas afectadas solo cuando la información a cambiar es diferente

Tags: sql-server, update

buenos días.

Mi consulta es referente a la sentencia **UPDATE** y las filas afectadas. En SQL Server la cantidad de filas afectadas se reconoce al momento de ejecutarla, aún si los datos que se envían para actualizar son los mismos.

Lo que quiero es considerar el cambio solo cuando los datos que se están enviando son diferentes. Por ejemplo en MySQL no existe ese problema, el cambio se considera solo cuando la información a editar es diferente. Eso es lo que quiero hacer en SQL Server, no quiero crear un trigger, solo quiero implementar la lógica en un procedimiento almacenado, pero cuando verdaderamente haya un cambio en uno o mas campos.

**SQL Server** - Resultado 1 fila afectada

```
UPDATE Tabla1 SET Campo1 = Campo1 WHERE Codigo = 1
```

**MySQL** - Resultado 0 filas afectadas

```
UPDATE Tabla1 SET Campo1 = Campo1 WHERE Codigo = 1
```

Comment: Quizás esto te ayude con tu problema - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677517/update-if-different-changed)

Comment: ¿Te refieres a `ROW_COUNT()`?  en este sentido MySql cuenta igual las cosas que Sql-Server. ¿Seguro en la segunda sentencia, tienes un fila con Codigo = 1?

Comment: @Excorpion, gracias. Muy interesante el aporte. Lo estuve revisando y es una buena opción.